# Cauchy's integral theorem vs line integration of a function $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ over a closed curve

Tags: complex-analysis

Why is that when I cosider the following :

$f: \mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R} \quad f(x,y) \equiv a\quad a \in \mathbb{R}^+$ and I take the line integral of it over a closed curve then it will have a  positive value,
but when I do that for the following function:

$g:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}\quad g(z) \equiv c \quad c \in \mathbb{C} $

I will get zero according to Cauchy's integral theorem?
I don't see the difference, but I have the kind of intuition that the later function translates to the one variable case: $h:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R} \quad h(x) \equiv b \quad b \in \mathbb{R}$ where I integrate from a to b and then I integrate from b to a and add them together to get zero kind of making a one dimensional closed curve. What is the difference and can I build on this intuition to get it? Souldn't be there some kind of isomorphism between f and g conrtadicting Cauchy's integral theorem? Did I miss some kind of restriction (maybe in the theorem) which makes a real difference between f and g?

[Cauchy's integral theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_theorem)

Comment: can you expand your calculations for a closed curve for the real function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line integral of a function is usually done with respect to the curve length element, the $ds$, while the Cauchy integral is done with respect to $dz$.  To see the difference, the line integral is
$$
\int_\gamma c \, ds = c ~ \text{length} (\gamma) .
$$
The integral in Cauchy is
$$
\int_\gamma c \, dz ,
$$
where $dz = dx +idy$.  So it is really the line integral
$$
\int_\gamma c \, (dx +idy)
=
\int_\gamma c \, dx + i \int_\gamma c \, dy ,
$$
and each one of these is zero.  So these are very different integrals.

Perhaps write down the thing in terms of parametrization, say $u(t)+iv(t)$.   Then $ds = \sqrt{(u'(t))^2+(v'(t))^2}\, dt$ and $dx = u'(t) dt$ and $dy = v'(t) dt$.